# Deploying to real iPhone became very slow at CopyingFile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Deploying from Visual Studio for Mac (latest version 8.8.8) to my iPhone (latest iOS version 14.3) has become very slow, much slower than I remember.

As a test I'm deploying a very simple app (almost a bare project) and it's taking *over 3 minutes (!)* to get it done.

In the 'Deploying to device' window it takes ages to complete copying:

```
CopyingFile - Path: /Users/adamsfamily/Documents/VisualStudio/sample-app/sample/sample/sample.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.3-14.3/sample.iOS.app/META-INF/com.apple.ZipMetadata.plist
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 10%
...
CopyingFile - Path: /Users/adamsfamily/Documents/VisualStudio/sample-app/sample/sample/sample.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.3-14.3/sample.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 10%
...
```

I am deploying over WiFi in my local area network. I make an Ookla speed test to verify my connection and both my Mac and my iPhone are **well over 100Mbps**.

The total size of the bundle is ~170MB.

Any tricks that can speed it up?

Comment: After restarting my iPhone and Visual Studio for Mac (not sure which one was necessary) deploying got faster by roughly 5-10x. I'd say it's back to normal. Still unsure what caused the slowness but hopes this helps someone!

Comment: UPDATE: Ok it seems that 4 days out of 5 it's very slow… Currently one deploy >3 minutes :( 1 day out of 5 it's fast. On the same infrastructure, same network performance :( I can't really explain why :(